# WTV in Opencv's Opencl code for Image resizing

Tags: opencv, opencl

What does WTV stands for in the following Opencl code?
I can't find much info for that. The code is from Opencv for processing on gpu.

__

```
kernel void resizeAREA(__global const uchar * src, int src_step, int src_offset, int src_rows, int src_cols,
                             __global uchar * dst, int dst_step, int dst_offset, int dst_rows, int dst_cols,
                             float ifx, float ify, __global const int * ofs_tab,
                             __global const int * map_tab, __global const float * alpha_tab)
    {
        int dx = get_global_id(0);
        int dy = get_global_id(1);

    if (dx < dst_cols && dy < dst_rows)
    {
        int dst_index = mad24(dy, dst_step, dst_offset);

        __global const int * xmap_tab = map_tab;
        __global const int * ymap_tab = (__global const int *)(map_tab + (src_cols << 1));
        __global const float * xalpha_tab = alpha_tab;
        __global const float * yalpha_tab = (__global const float *)(alpha_tab + (src_cols << 1));
        __global const int * xofs_tab = ofs_tab;
        __global const int * yofs_tab = (__global const int *)(ofs_tab + dst_cols + 1);

        int xk0 = xofs_tab[dx], xk1 = xofs_tab[dx + 1];
        int yk0 = yofs_tab[dy], yk1 = yofs_tab[dy + 1];

        int sy0 = ymap_tab[yk0], sy1 = ymap_tab[yk1 - 1];
        int sx0 = xmap_tab[xk0], sx1 = xmap_tab[xk1 - 1];

        WTV sum = (WTV)(0), buf;
        int src_index = mad24(sy0, src_step, src_offset);

        for (int sy = sy0, yk = yk0; sy <= sy1; ++sy, src_index += src_step, ++yk)
        {
            WTV beta = (WTV)(yalpha_tab[yk]);
            buf = (WTV)(0);

            for (int sx = sx0, xk = xk0; sx <= sx1; ++sx, ++xk)
            {
                WTV alpha = (WTV)(xalpha_tab[xk]);
                buf += convertToWTV(loadpix(src + mad24(sx, TSIZE, src_index))) * alpha;
            }
            sum += buf * beta;
        }

        storepix(convertToT(sum), dst + mad24(dx, TSIZE, dst_index));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not defined in the source you shared. It appears to be a type, like `float`. Just guessing: it's defined using "-D WTV=something" while compiling the kernel.